# How do you show what function you are in in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I show what function I'm in? I'd like to be able to see where ever I place my cursor, to see what function I'm in preferably in the footer tray bar.

Comment: Also look at enabling "breadcrumbs".  It'll show what function you are in, but not in the status bar.

Comment: I had "breadcrumbs" enabled by default and just had to presh Ctrl+Shift+. to show this information.

Comment: This is the breadcrumbs documentation https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_breadcrumbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a functional extension for this mentioned in the GitHub issue:

- Show the current function/method name in the toolbar:
  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32869

Here is the extension:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amos402.scope-bar

Comment: do i need to do anything special to run this after i install the extension ? i don't see the function name or any change after i installed the extension

Comment: You should find it at the bottom right of the toolbar, just to the left of the Ln xxx, Col yy numbers.

Answer (score 12):

You can try sticky scroll.
ref https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70#_editor-sticky-scroll

[image]

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in the comments, this can be achieved without any extension by opening command palette and selecting "View: Toggle Breadcrumbs"

Comment: This only goes as far as the file name in remote-ssh, not the function name.